# setup a constant inflation rate every era

Tags: substrate-node-template, pallet-staking, rewards, validator-set

trying to figure out a way to have a constant inflation rate for every era e.g to a 5% of total supply so any hint or clue how it goes with this configuration without setting min/max inflation into the curve:

```
const REWARD_CURVE: PiecewiseLinear<'static> = curve!(
        min_inflation: 0_025_000,
        max_inflation: 0_100_000,
        ideal_stake: 0_500_000,
        falloff: 0_050_000,
        max_piece_count: 40,
        test_precision: 0_005_000,
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the piecewise linear curve yourself. Something like this:

```rust
    const CURVE: PiecewiseLinear = PiecewiseLinear {
        points: &[
            (sp_arithmetic::Perbill::from_parts(0_000_000_000), sp_arithmetic::Perbill::from_parts(0_050_000_000)),
            (sp_arithmetic::Perbill::from_parts(1_000_000_000), sp_arithmetic::Perbill::from_parts(0_050_000_000)),
        ],
        maximum: sp_arithmetic::Perbill::from_parts(0_050_000_000),
    };
```